# Vpn disconnect after 5 min

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, linux-mint, openvpn

I have a problem with my VPN disconnecting. Every time I connect I get disconnected after approximatively 5 min and I have no idea why and can't find relevant info on the web.

Here is a terminal output:

```
sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-euro1-tcp443.ovpn

Wed Apr 25 19:03:19 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Wed Apr 25 19:03:19 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: *******
Enter Auth Password: ********
Wed Apr 25 19:03:28 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Apr 25 19:03:28 2018 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Wed Apr 25 19:03:28 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Wed Apr 25 19:03:28 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443 [nonblock]
Wed Apr 25 19:03:29 2018 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443
Wed Apr 25 19:03:29 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Apr 25 19:03:29 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443
Wed Apr 25 19:03:30 2018 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443, sid=dd467348 e8297078
Wed Apr 25 19:03:30 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Apr 25 19:03:30 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Wed Apr 25 19:03:30 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
Wed Apr 25 19:03:32 2018 [vpnbook.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 SENT CONTROL [vpnbook.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS  8.8.4.4,dhcp-option DNS  91.239.100.100,route 10.9.0.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.9.0.22 10.9.0.21,peer-id 0'
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified>
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1563
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.178.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlx0018e756fdf2 HWADDR=00:18:e7:56:fd:f2
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Wed Apr 25 19:03:34 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.9.0.22 peer 10.9.0.21
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 /sbin/ip route add 176.126.237.217/32 via 192.168.178.1
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.21
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.21
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 /sbin/ip route add 10.9.0.1/32 via 10.9.0.21
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Apr 25 19:14:11 2018 [vpnbook.com] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Apr 25 19:14:11 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed Apr 25 19:14:11 2018 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed Apr 25 19:14:16 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Apr 25 19:14:16 2018 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Wed Apr 25 19:14:16 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Wed Apr 25 19:14:16 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443 [nonblock]
Wed Apr 25 19:14:17 2018 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443
Wed Apr 25 19:14:17 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Apr 25 19:14:17 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:443
Wed Apr 25 19:14:19 2018 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Wed Apr 25 19:14:19 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

I can't tell if the problem is on my side, meaning the PC I don't have access to the router unfortunately, or from the ISP/VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The log file shows a disconnect after 10 minutes due to inactivity:

```
Wed Apr 25 19:03:36 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Apr 25 19:14:11 2018 [vpnbook.com] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
```

If you were indeed actively using the VPN you're going to need to raise this with the operator of the server endpoint.

You could also provide us with the timeout settings from your client OpenVPN configuration (XXXXXX the remote host name, certificate details, and any username/password) to see if the timeout setting is mentioned there (it would be listed as a value of 600 seconds).

You can work-around the issue by starting a `ping` in another window, but it really would be better to address the underlying issue.

```
ping -i 30 8.8.8.8    # Send a packet every 30 seconds
```